# Is There a Way to Flip a Sprite in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a 2D Unity project where it's a platformer but you controller the character with gravity. For the game, I need to make it so that when you turn the gravity say, up, it should flip the sprite upside down.   This is my code so far in the C# script I have that is attached to the character game object.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class GravityController2d : MonoBehaviour
{
enum GravityDirection { Down, Left, Up, Right };
public Animator animator;
public GameObject Game_object;
private Vector3 chestPos = new Vector3(6.69f, 1.45f, 0.0f);

void Start()
{
    Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(0f, -9.8f);
}

void FixedUpdate()
{   
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
    {
        Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(0f, -9.8f);
        //flip
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(-9.8f, 0f);
            //flip
        }
    
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(0f, 9.8f);
            //flip
        }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            Physics2D.gravity = new Vector2(9.8f, 0f);
            //flip
        }

    
} 
}
```

Edit: The tag I used was Unity2D but it auto corrected it to unity3d so thats my excuse for that.

Also: It needs to also be able to flip 90 degrees in case the player switches the gravity to go to the left/right

Comment: `unity2d` and `unity3d` are synonyms .. its the same Game engine just ignoring the Z axis ;) I also doubt that you would **always** wan to flip the sprite ... Probably only if it is not facing in the correct direction ;)

Comment: Welcome new user, you're just looking for flipX .. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html

Comment: Uhh .. which Der already perfectly explained, sorry!  :)

Comment: I need to rotate it only 90 degrees and I need it because I want to flip it when I change to gravity in my game

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to a `SpriteRenderer` you can use [`SpriteRenderer.flipX`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html) and [`SpriteRenderer.flipY`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipY.html) and check in which direction your gravity goes like e.g.

```
// Link in the Inspector
[SerializeField] SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;
```

and then

```
private void UpdateSpriteFlip()
{
    // The conditions according to your needs of course
    spriteRenderer.flipX = Physics2D.gravity.x < 0;
    spriteRenderer.flipY = Physics2D.gravity.y > 0;
}
```

Comment: pff way easier to change y rotation by 180, nerd xD

Comment: @Leoverload , no definitely use the flip function.  It's a subtle issue about whether or not both sides are rendered, etc.  flip always works and it's the normal thing to do, and doesn't change the physics, direction logic etc.

Comment: Does this still work on the z axis? Does this work if you only want to rotate it 90 degrees? How would you do that?

Comment: @AbhijitPrajapati it is flipping the sprite as you asked ;) It doesn't rotate it at all ..  for rotations you would again either use `transform.rotation`, `transform.Rotate` or `rigidbody.rotation` etc

Comment: @derHugo But will this answer be able to flip/rotate it only 90 degrees?

Comment: @AbhijitPrajapati no .. because this would be a rotation (see my comment before) not a flip

Comment: @derHugo Ok.. if I wanted to rotate it I'm assuming I could just use transform.Rotate right?

Comment: This answer didnt directly solve my problem but It helped to I will mark it as a succesful answer