# Flip 2D bullet Sprite when character facing left of right

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, flip

When I shoot to the right bullet is going right and the Sprite bullet animation is facing the right side but when I shoot to the left bullet is going to the left but Sprite animation is still facing the right side how do I fix this?

Comment: Does [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/952558/how-to-flip-sprite-horizontally-in-unity-2d.html) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65629782/2983568) help?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about your project and how everything is structured so I can only offer you some dummy code:

Right after instantiating the bullet, just flip the bullet Sprite:

```
public GameObject bulletPrefab;

public void Shoot(bool movesLeft)
{
    GameObject bulletObj = Instantiate(bulletPrefab);

    if (movesLeft) // flip Sprite when the player shoots to the left
    {
        Vector2 scale = bulletObj.transform.localScale;
        scale.x = -scale.x;
        bulletObj.transform.localScale = scale;
    }

    // set position, movement, ...
}
```

Comment: I'm new to this as you can see by my question haha this code does not work for me or I don't know how to use it.. anyway I give up I'm just gonna use a bullet Sprite that look the same in both directions like a sphere or something.. thank you very much

Comment: I just want to flipX on a bullet Sprite when player is facing left haha